# Signout with Google Sign-In option crashes with java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet

Tags: google-signin

I am trying to use Google Sign-In for my android app from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in).
I am able to log-in succesfully with the google account & able to fetch all the details. However, when ever I try to logout it fails with following error :

```
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

I have read many answers suggesting to create googleClientApi object inside onCreate() and that's what I am doing.I have added callbacks for connected and suspended but the connect never goes into suspended mode.

Following is my code snippet :

```
  public static void doInit(Context ctx, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) { 

          GoogleSignInOptions gso = new  GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
                 GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ctx)
                .enableAutoManage(fragmentActivity , googleAuth)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(googleAuth)
                .build();
    }

    public static Intent doGoogleLogIn() {
        return Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    public static boolean doGoogleLogOut() {



        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                    }
                });
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d("Signin", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        System.out.println("Connected...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        System.out.println("Suspened....");
    }
```

The only thing that is doubtful to me is, when I login and create googleApiClient object, its created from different activity that the one which I am using for logout. I don't suspect this is the reason because when the activity loaded, the isConnected on googleApiClient is returning true. However, the moment I do some UI action(Click on Logout), it starts returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primary requirement was to login and logout from different activities.**

Finally I managed to make it work.

The actual cause of the error is "enableAutoManage" invocation at the time of Building Client object.

The API doc [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#enableAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,%20int,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)) suggests that it would automatically do the life cycle management by calling methods on onStart & onStop of the activity.

Therefore, if you want to use the same object across different activities then you should avoid calling "enableAutoManage" and invoke apiObject.connect(preferably in onStart of activity) and apiObject.disconnect() or logout (preferably in onStop of activity) manually.